# why i can't access variable which i declare in nested class?

Tags: java

My friends,  I have three class in my project

Main class :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student();
    }
}
```

and Student class :

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private Date date = new Date();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

and Date class :

```
public class Date {
    private int d;
    private int m;
    private int y;

    public int getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(int d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public int getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(int m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

first of all, when I instance `Student` in `main` class, java makes the structure like this:

[image: Structure]

What I mean is when we instance `Student` class in `main` class, java read `Student` class line by line
for Example : `String name , int id , Date date = new Date();`

because `Date` has got 3 variables in it, we can say When we instance `Student` class we have 5 variables.

for Example `Student s1 = new Student();`
we have String `name`, int `id`, int `d`, int `m`, int `y` for `s1`.
my question is why we can't directly access `s1.y` or `s1.m` or `s1.d`?

for Example for initialize name we can use this code : `s1.setName();`
but why we can't use this : `s1.setDate().setM()`???

Comment: "why we can't directly access s1.y"? Because `y` is `private`. You need to use the getter to access the field's data, so instead of `s1.setDate().setM()` it neets to be `s1.getDate().setM()`.

Comment: How getter allows us to access y field and why setter can't do this?

Comment: A nested class is a class that is declared inside another class.  There are no nested classes in your example.   So your question's title is misleading.

Comment: Your code declares the getters and setters as public, so that other classes can access them. A setter can access and modify the field, but does not return the value. That's the purpose of the getter.

Comment: If you are doing an exercise that requires you to create your own `Date` class, obviously do that. For any other purpose including all production code use `LocalDate` and do not create your own class for a date.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute following code

```java
        Student s1 = new Student();
```

you are actually creating 2 objects:

1. a `Student` object, which you can access through `s1` reference.
2. a `Date` object, which is automatically created altogether with above Student.

Those are two separate objects. `Student` has only 3 properties (name, id, date) and `Date` object has also 3 properties (d,m,y).

To access a property of an object you need to use its reference.
Because `s1` references Student object, you can use it to access members of this object. However in order to access members of `Date` object, you need to obtain its reference, which is stored in the `date` property in the Student object.

Therefore with `s1.getDate()` you get this reference and then you can use it to access members of a Date (i.e. its set*** methods)

Comment: When we instace Student class, when java read this line >>> Date date = new Date(); Date class Create automatic because it's in Student class, and when Date class create, java give it a reference address by default, what i want to say is why we have to get Date reference by getDate method ? why setDate method can't access variables in Date class when it has got Date reference by default?

Comment: "However in order to access members of Date object, you need to obtain its reference"         why we need to obtain reference of Date class, i mean why setDate can't access to Date reference?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean when you say that "why setDate can't access date reference"? It can access it because it's in the Student class where reference is stored in the date field.

Comment: you did this s1.getDate().setd();   i want to know why we use getDate here? why we don't use s1.setDate().setd(); ? i mean when we want to set a stuff in field we use setter not getter...

Comment: You use `getDate()` to obtain a reference to the Date object. Then you call `setId` on this referene to modify some value within.

Comment: To give you real world example: Imagine that you have a bag in the locker. In order to put something into the bag, you have to first *get* the bag from the locker and then *set* something into the bag.

Comment: ok, but can you tell me about what getter method do in this Example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a nested class is a class that is declared inside another class. There are no nested classes in your example.  So your question's title is misleading.

You ask this:

> My question is why we can't directly access `s1.y` or `s1.m` or `s1.d`?

There are two reasons:

Reason #1: Because `y`, `m` and `d` ore not fields of the `Student` class.  They are fields of your `Date` class.   So, if you were (hypothetically) able to access them you would do it like as `s1.date.y`, `s1.date.m` and `s1.date.d`.

But that wouldn't work because of Reason #2.

Reason #2: Because `y`, `m`, `d` and indeed `date` have been declared as private.  The `private` access means that code outside of the class is not allowed to access them.

---

Your second pair of examples is **materially different** to the first example.  Now you are *calling methods* on the respective objects, not accessing their fields.

> For example for initialize name we can use this code: `s1.setName();`

Close, but not correct.  You have to write `s1.setName("John Smith");` or some such.  The point is that `setName()` requires a `String` argument.  (That is how you declared it!!)

> But why we can't use this : `s1.setDate().setM();`

To understand why this doesn't work, we need to explain what it actually says:

1. Get the object reference in the `s1` variable.
2. Call the `setDate()` method on that object.
3. Call the `setM()` method on the object *returned* by the `setDate()` call.

So why doesn't it work?  In this case there are 3 reasons:

- The `setDate` method expects  a parameter.  You haven't supplied one.
- The `setDate` method is a `void` method.  It doesn't return anything.  So there is nothing to call `setM` on.
- The `setM` method expects a parameter too.

In fact ... your big mistake here is that you are using the wrong method.  To set the `m` field of the `date` of a `Student` you would use something like `s1.getDate().setM(6);`

1. Get the object reference in the `s1` variable.
2. Call the `getDate()` method on that object to **get** the `Date` object.
3. Call the `setM()` method on the `Date` object.

---

You need to think about what the methods actually do.  You don't call `setDate` in the above because `setDate` *replaces the entire date object with a different object*.  And that is not what you are (presumably) trying to do.